# Error from Google API PHP Config.php file - Fatal Error - Call to undefined function sys_get_temp_dir()

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, tempdir

The Google API PHP Client library has a file named **Config.php**.  I'm getting an error from that file, from line 139.

```
'directory' => sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client'
```

The error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sys_get_temp_dir() in C:\Users\NoName\Documents\academic-being-90217\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Config.php on line 139

Here is a link to the file in GitHub:

[GitHub file - Config.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Config.php)

Why am I getting that error?

Do I need to create a **temp** directory?  There is no **temp** directory defined.

The PHP function `sys_get_temp_dir()`

> Returns the path of the directory PHP stores temporary files in by default

I'm running this code from Google App Engine Launcher on my computer.  Does that make a difference, as opposed to running it from the host server?

I created a `temp` directory under `google-api-php-client/src/Google` but that didn't stop the error.

I'm beginning to wonder if this is an internal issue with Google App Engine Launcher, and whether the `sys_get_temp_dir()` function is available to it.

If all I do is run just one line of code:

```
<?php

  $thisIsATest = sys_get_temp_dir();
  return;
```

I get the same error.  So that error has nothing to do with any other part of the code.

I guess that I could hard code a directory path, and make sure there is a folder there to be available to use.

```
'directory' => 'src/Google/temp/Google_Client'
```

Well, if I hard code a directory path for that line, I don't get an error any more.  But I'm not sure I've got the path set up correctly.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Also, open your `php.ini` file and search for `disable_functions`. Is `sys_get_temp_dir` there?

Comment: I've got the app.yaml set to 5.5.  `runtime: php55`

Comment: I don't have a `php.ini` file.

Comment: Yes, you do. Open a terminal (Windows button, type `cmd` and hit Enter). Type `php --ini` and hit Enter. There should be a "Loaded Configuration File:".

Comment: Your right.  I have one php.ini file in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Google_appengine\demos\php\minishell`  The contents are:  `; Re-enable these soft disabled functions for minishell users.
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpinfo, php_uname, php_sapi_name"`  When I use: `php --ini` on the windows command line I get the msg:  `php is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc`

Comment: How are you running your app? Did you use the launcher or command line?

Comment: Launcher,  don't ever use the command line.

Comment: The launcher should pick up the bundled PHP interpreter automatically, and if you're using php55, sys_get_temp_dir() should return a temporary in-memory file (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions)